# How to keep just lines contain specific string in grep?

Tags: text, grep

I have text file. I need print just these lines which contain one of specific string for example:
Text file:

```
Car, bold 231212 /Fds
House pen 232123 /RYF
game kon 342442 /ksgj
mess three 42424 /UTR
```

And I need just keep lines contain Fds or UTR

Output:

```
Car, bold 231212 /Fds
mess three 42424 /UTR
```

How to do these in grep?

Thank you

Answer (score 12):

Try doing this, the `OR` operator is the *pipe* :  `|` :

```
grep -E 'Fds|UTR' file
```

or

```
grep -E '(Fds|UTR)' file
```

or

```
grep -P '(?:Fds|UTR)' file
```

or

```
grep 'Fds\|UTR' file
```

Comment: NP, I saw this joke yesterday, maybe you ? :)

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with a single command, fortunately.  grep can be used to search either files directly or any data piped to it.  In this case, we'll just use it to search a single file.

grep can use regular expressions, which will be used to allow for "or" behavior (as denoted by the "|", or pipe symbol) when searching.  The command you're looking for should be

```
grep 'Fds\|UTR' filename
```

That backslash is important.  Without it, grep searches for the string "Fds|UTR", which obviously doesn't exist in the search text.

Alternately, one could use `egrep`.

```
egrep 'Fds|UTR' filename
```

Comment: `bash` catch the pipe ? And he don't catch it with `grep -E 'Fds|UTR' file` ? Seems at least quite vague or erroneous :/

Comment: To clarify, the `-E` flag negates the need for the backslash by forcing `grep` to interpret the pattern as a regular expression.  Other options are available, of course.

Comment: Still erroneous, try this in a shell : `$ echo 'foo|bar'` There's no switch and the shell don't `fork()` nor wait user input nor try to send foo to bar pipe.
`

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with grep too. sputnick has given an answer. As an alternative, sed solution:

```
sed '/Fds\|UTR/!d' file
```

Comment: requester suggested he want grep only, though sed is a cool alternative!